# Is it possible to get Instagram home feed (landing screen) from their API?

Tags: api, instagram, social-networking

Is it possible to get Instagram home feed (landing screen) from their API or is it deprecated?

The current docs only mention getting user's feed (which I assume is your own uploaded photos or other uers uploaded photos).

I'd like to display a user's timeline, not user's uploaded pictures.

Is it only possible if you struck a deal with Instagram? Which is what I assume apps like `Grids` and other are doing - since they also display stories, DMs etc, functionalities that are not available from public API at all.